# Is there any exact previous node in css?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I want to find the previous sibling of all my  element and changes its color.
below is an example:

```
    <ul>
        <li> 1
        <li>  2
        <ul>
            <li> 3
            <li> 4
            <ul>
                <li> 5
                <li> 6
            </ul>
         </ul>
         <li>  7
        <ul>
            <li> 8
            <li> 9
            <ul>
                <li> 10
                <li> 11
            </ul>
         </ul>
    </ul>
```

as per the example, i want nodes 2,4,7,9 to be affected by css/sass.
We don't have any classes to elements nor can we use any script.

Comment: [There is no previous sibling selector in css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/9718056). Also, it is not semantically correct to write an `ul` inside another `ul`, you should wrap it inside a `li`.

Comment: Can you please update our html structure, its too messy without closing `li` tags , and there is no previous selector in pure `css` you need `jS` for that

Answer (score 0):

Like Arkellys already pointed out, there is no actual “previous sibling” selector in CSS/SASS.

But there is an `+` selector (adjacent sibling combinator). Maybe you could try this because in your example it looks a bit like you want to select the second `li` for each list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

```css
ul > li {
  color: black;
}

ul > li + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <ul>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>7
        <ul>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9
                <ul>
                    <li>10</li>
                    <li>11</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can Use

```
ul>li{
    color:black;
    &+li{
        color:red;
    }
    &>&>&{
        color:black;
    }
}
```